# Azure Service fabric - How do I configure the time interval before container is force terminated

Tags: azure, docker, azure-service-fabric

I have my application deployed in Azure Service fabric. I want to configure the docker stop command to use the custom timeout before termination and killing command.
I have seen, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers#configure-time-interval-before-container-is-force-terminated
This documentation tells us to use the `ContainerDeactivationTimeout` parameter for setting the same.
But couldn't figure out how and where.
Can anyone with experience in Service fabric, help me out in this
I have files, ApplicationManifest.xml & ServiceManifest.xml with me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Azure Service Fabric:

1. Navigate to your instance in the Azure portal and click on "Custom Fabric Settings" on the left instance navbar.
2. Click the "+ Add new" link at the bottom of the list that comes up.
3. Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers#configure-time-interval-before-container-is-force-terminated) you cited, select "Hosting" as the section name, enter "ContainerDeactivationTimeout" as the parameter name and specify the value you wish to use (noting that the number will be the timeout interval measured in seconds).
4. Apply the setting. It will trigger a cluster upgrade which should wrap up in a few minutes.